# How to get nested documents by field value from other documents (ElasticSearch)?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

example query:

[localhost:8080/content/child/123](http://localhost:8080/content/childs/123)

This query should return doc where parent id is equal to "123", then I need to get id from the returned document and search in Elastic for documents where parent id is equal to this id.

example result :

`{
  "id": "test",
  "parentId" : "123",
  "name" : "bambo"
}`

`{
  "id": "someId",
  "parentId" : "test",
  "name" : "bambo 2"
}`

Comment: GET /content/child/123 means searching for the specific document where `_index=content; _type=child; _id=123`. So in your example, the query matches neither of the two documents. What do you want to return? Both documents, or just the second one? Not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `GET /content/child/123` means searching for the specific document where `_index=content; _type=child; _id=123`, which is not what you're looking for. The `_id` field is completely different from your `id` and `parentId` fields.

As far as I know, ES does not currently have a "nested search" feature as you described. You need to do two separate searches.

---

To search for documents with field ("parentId") containing a specific value ("123"), you need the following search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "parentId": "123"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After your first search, the response will be a JSON object `resp`. You may find a list of returned results in `resp["hits"]["hits"]`. Then, parse a result object to obtain the `id` field you want. For example, `resp["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["id"]` will give you the `id` field.

Check out the documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html

Comment: it's not query to elastic but to some rest controller /123 is parent id and I want to get all documents with this value in field parent id then I need to take them ids and search for nested documents if they parent id equals to one of this ids then I need to return them too.